# JSON for PHP + MYSQL error

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, json

My client sent me this JSON so I can loop and save the data in Mysql. I just can not get it because it's different from what I work at;

Can someone give me some hint and what is the difference from one format to another.

Error presented is: Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach () in line 28

foreach ($ json_data ['service_devices'] as $ key => $ value) {

Formator EX I've ever worked with:

```
{
     "ordem_de_servico": [
         {
             "oser_numero_os": 23940493,
             "oser_address_name": NAME;
```

**CUSTOMER JSON**

```
ordem_de_servico:
        {  
           "oser_numero_os":23940493,
           "oser_dt_abertura":"28/03/2018",
           "servico":{  
              "serv_cod_servico":60,
              "serv_descr_servico":"CORTE POR DEBITO"
           },
           "cliente":{  
              "clie_ident_cliente":638617,
              "nome":"MARIA APARECIDA FERREIRA DO NASCIMENTO"
           },
           "unidade_consumidora":{  
              "unid_ident_uc":2436434,
              "logr_nome_logr_expandido":"R JOSE GUIMARAES"
           },
           "faturas":[  
              {  
                 "total_fatura":"88.44",
                 "ftcd_mes_ano_fatmto":"2017-04-01"
              },
              {  
                 "total_fatura":"45.16",
                 "ftcd_mes_ano_fatmto":"2017-03-01"
              }
           ]
    }
```

**My last attempt**

```
<?php
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "";
    $dbname = "webservice";
    // Create connection
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    // Check connection
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    } 


    // Read JSON file
    $json = file_get_contents('oss.json');

    //Decode JSON
    $json_data = json_decode($json,true);


    foreach($json_data['ordens_de_servico'] as $key => $value){
        $os = $value["oser_numero_os"];
        $data_abertura = $value["oser_dt_abertura"];

        foreach($json_data['ordens_de_servico'][$key]['faturas'] as $index => $row){

            $valorParcelas = $row["total_fatura"];
            $sql = "SELECT numero_os FROM os WHERE numero_os = '$os'";
            $result = $conn->query($sql);
            if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
                    echo "PULAR FATURA"."<p>";
            }else {     
            $sql = "INSERT INTO faturas (valorParcelas, numero_os) VALUES ('$valorParcelas', '$os')";
                if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
                    echo "<strong>".$valorParcelas." - FATURA OK"."</strong>"."<p>";
                } else {
                    echo "Error Fatura";
                }
            }
        }
        $sql = "SELECT numero_os FROM os WHERE numero_os = '$os'";
            $result = $conn->query($sql);
            if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
                    echo "PULAR"."<p>";
            }
            else{
                $sql = "INSERT INTO os (numero_os, data_abertura) VALUES ('$os', '$data_abertura')";
                if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
                    echo "<strong>".$os." - GRAVADO"."</strong>"."<p>";
                } else {
                    echo "Error";
                }
            }

    }

    $conn->close();
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the line:

```
foreach($json_data['ordens_de_servico'] as $key => $value){
```

To:

```
foreach($json_data as $key => $value){
```

Since the new data doesn't have the outer element `ordens_de_servico`

Or you could edit the JSON file and add that element (don't forget to add the closing braces at the end as well.

Edit the first two lines of the file:

```
ordem_de_servico:
        {
```

To:

{
     "ordem_de_servico": [

And change the end of the file:

```
        }
```

To:

```
    ]
}
```

Comment: I made the change but I did not succeed, the error continues on the same line

Comment: Just after the line ```$json_data = json_decode($json,true);``` add ```echo "<p>JSON:<pre>".print_r($json_data,true)."</pre></p>";``` and look at the results, that should give you an idea about how to reference the data. If not obvious, edit your question and show the first few lines of the results.

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON is incorrect. The main problem is json data itself which is not valid for `json_encode()` to generate PHP array.

**First Possible solution**:Remove `ordem_de_servico:` from our customer json and that will gonna work.

For `json_decode();` method the json data must be valid and valid data is

```
{  
    "oser_numero_os":23940493,
    "oser_dt_abertura":"28/03/2018",
    "servico":{  
        "serv_cod_servico":60,
        "serv_descr_servico":"CORTE POR DEBITO"
    },
    "cliente":{  
        "clie_ident_cliente":638617,
        "nome":"MARIA APARECIDA FERREIRA DO NASCIMENTO"
    },
    "unidade_consumidora":{  
        "unid_ident_uc":2436434,
        "logr_nome_logr_expandido":"R JOSE GUIMARAES"
    },
    "faturas":[  
        {  
            "total_fatura":"88.44",
            "ftcd_mes_ano_fatmto":"2017-04-01"
        },
        {  
            "total_fatura":"45.16",
            "ftcd_mes_ano_fatmto":"2017-03-01"
        }
    ]
}
```

**Second possible solution**:What you can do is remove `ordem_de_servico:` string from your customer json data or make your json provider provide valid json data as follows with `ordem_de_servico:`.

```
{
    "ordem_de_servico":{  
        "oser_numero_os":23940493,
        "oser_dt_abertura":"28/03/2018",
        "servico":{  
            "serv_cod_servico":60,
            "serv_descr_servico":"CORTE POR DEBITO"
        },
        "cliente":{  
            "clie_ident_cliente":638617,
            "nome":"MARIA APARECIDA FERREIRA DO NASCIMENTO"
        },
        "unidade_consumidora":{  
            "unid_ident_uc":2436434,
            "logr_nome_logr_expandido":"R JOSE GUIMARAES"
        },
        "faturas":[  
            {  
                "total_fatura":"88.44",
                "ftcd_mes_ano_fatmto":"2017-04-01"
            },
            {  
                "total_fatura":"45.16",
                "ftcd_mes_ano_fatmto":"2017-03-01"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Look at the valid JSON format for `json_decode()` and there is not different types of json data only one type i.e. json.